# Enable Pinch zoom for google map in a website

Tags: google-maps

We use google map in our website, I need to enable pinch zoom using touch pad,
How can I enable it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature request in the public issue tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4599

If you read the discussion you will see a workaround proposed by developers:

https://github.com/clshortfuse/googleMapsAPITouchWorkaround/blob/master/addTouchSupport.js

Another workaround can be fount at

https://github.com/bamnet/map_sandbox/tree/master/forceTouchUI

**UPDATE (January 2017)**

The [issue 4599](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4599) was merged into [issue 6425](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6425) which was marked as Fixed by Google.

> This issue was finally fixed in late November, in the experimental version (3.27).
>   Let us know if there are remaining problems...